# To the World of Death?

Tags: planets, environment, atmosphere

In a nearby star system to Earth, there lies an... interesting planet. Thirty thousand atmospheres of pressure, "surface" temperature of 5,500 kelvin, an atmosphere made of gaseous sillicates and vapourised *iron*, it makes Venus look like a paradise. So let's give it an appropriate name, like Hell.

Now, due to Alien Space Magic a portal 5m wide opens on the surface of Earth connecting to the surface of Hell at the present day. What happens to the area around the portal on Earth, and could we send a probe through to Hell that would survive long enough to send back data?

Comment: The fellow who opened that portal is gonna get sued.

Comment: Is there any sort of airlock around the portal? On one side, or both? I think it'd be a good idea to make one (or two). Or maybe the airlock is somehow intrinsic to the Alien Space Magic portal. Is it? How does this work?

Comment: I think "World of Death" is pejorative.  It might be a fine world for the natives.

Comment: Is that Celsius, Kelvin, or Fahrenheit?

Comment: @Nosajimiki-ReinstateMonica, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @user535733, No... the fellow who opened that portal is going to *die*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Looking for [Choked Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow)

$\dot{m} = C_d A \sqrt{\gamma \rho_0 P_0 ({2 \over {\gamma + 1}})^{{\gamma + 1} \over {\gamma -1}}}$

- $\dot{m}$ is the choked mass flow rate, the value we are looking for
- $C_d$ is the discharge coefficient. Let's go with 1.0 for space magic
- A is the area of the portal. A 5m diameter circular portal has an area of ~19.6 $m^2$
- $\gamma$ is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) of the gas. For gaseous silicates we'll use 1.29
- $\rho_0$ is the gas density. We'll need to figure that out.
- $P_0$ is the upstream pressure. 30,000 atmospheres, or 3.045 gigapascals (GPa).

### Calculating Density of Death World's Air

The equation for density is $ P = \rho R_{specific} T $

- P is 3.0 GPa ($3 \times 10^9$ Pa)
- T is 5,500 Kelvin

$R_{specific} = {R \over M}$

- R is the gas constant 8,314 ${m^2 kg} \over {s^{2} K mol}$
- M is molar mass. For silizate ($SiO_2$) gas, it's Si (28) + O (16) x 2 = 60 $g \over {mol}$

$R_{specific}$ = 138.6

$\rho_0$ = $P \over { R_{specific} T }$ = 3,995 $kg \over {m^3}$

### Final Flow Rate

Inserting Variables and Solving :

- $\dot{m} = C_d A \sqrt{\gamma \rho_0 P_0 ({2 \over {\gamma + 1}})^{{\gamma + 1} \over {\gamma -1}}}$
- $\dot{m} = (1.0) (19.6) \sqrt{(1.29) (3,395) (3,045,000,000) ({2 \over {(1.29) + 1}})^{{(1.29) + 1} \over {(1.29) -1}}}$
- $\dot{m} = 19.6 \sqrt{(1.29) (3,395) (3,045,000,000) ({2 \over {2.29}})^{{2.29} \over {0.29}}}$
- $\dot{m} = 19.6 \sqrt{(1.29) (3,395) (3,045,000,000) (0.87)^{7.89}}$
- $\dot{m} = 19.6 \sqrt{(1.57 \times 10^{13}) (0.34)}$
- $\dot{m} = 19.6 \sqrt{5.34 \times 10^{12}}$
- $\dot{m} = (19.6) (5.34 \times 10^{6})$
- $\dot{m} = (4.53 \times 10^7)$ $kg \over s$

The average velocity of that gas is $\dot{m} = \rho v A$. Which is 577 $m \over s$.

### Expansion and Cooling

After exiting the portal, the iron-laden silicate gas is expanding and cooling from 5,500 Kelvin and 30,000 atmospheres.

The speed of sound for this expanding death world gas is $a$ = $\sqrt{ \gamma R_{specific} T}$. $\gamma$ has a different meaning here. It's the adiabatic index, and for diatomic gasses it's 1.4 (not quite the tri-atomic SiO2; but using this for now). T is in Celsius instead of Kelvin.

- $a$ = $\sqrt{ (1.4) (138.6) (5,500) }$ = 1,032 $m \over s$

The death world gas is initially expanding from the portal at the it's speed of sound, 1,032 $m \over s$, or about Mach 3. Which would mean there's plenty of sound, noise, heat, and toxic vapor jetting out of this thing, but most of it is the higher-temperature, higher-pressure air expanding and cooling.

### Limits

Where does the expansion end? ${P_1 V_1} \over {T_1}$ = ${P_2 V_2} \over {T_2}$. $P_1 \over P_2$ is 30,000. $T_1 \over T_2$ is ~ 200.

The volume at which the gas reaches Earth temperature and pressure $V_2 \over V_1$ should be 150 times the exit volume. For a portal 5 meters wide, I'd estimate you'd need a grid 750 meters on a side to keep people clear.

### Heating

Some folks have asked about how much the portal to the death world starts to heat up the surrounding environment.

The heat passing through the portal is related to the mass flow rate, specific heat properties of the gas (glass), and the temperature difference between the portal and the environment

$\Delta Q = \dot{m} ( \Delta H_{vap} + \Delta H_{fus} + c \Delta T )$

- $\dot{m}$ was calculated above. $4.53 \times 10^7$ $kg \over s$
- $H_{vap}$ is 0 ([according to this source](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-much-heat-energy-in-molten-glass.789170/))
- $H_{fus}$ is 0 (same source)
- c is 0.8 ${kJ} \over K$
- $\Delta T$ is (5,500K - 300K = 5,200K)

Solving:

- $\Delta Q = 4.53 \times 10^7 ( 0 + 0 + (0.8) (5,200) ) = 1.88 \times 10^{11}$ $J \over s$ = 188 $TJ \over s$

If I've done that right, $\Delta Q$ is 188 ${TJ} \over {s}$. Or 188 terawatts.

For scope, 80 terajoules is the amount of energy released by the first atomic bomb test.

### Sound

Like the whistle of tea pot, or the rumble of an explosion, the portal will generate a sound that will carry for miles. I'd like the equation to figure out the frequency at the nozzle, but it escapes me at the moment.

### Visibility

Iron and silicon dioxide (glass) are both solids at Earth pressures and temperatures. The cooling dome of gas would project nearly 1 kilometer up, and look something like the ash clouds over erupting volcanoes.

### Survivability of a Probe

At 5,500 Kelvin, the atmosphere of the death world will even melt the most temperature-resistant material, [Tungsten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten). Additionally, the ground beneath the gate is a gas at death-world temperatures. You shouldn't take it for granted that the gate is not now floating inside a crater of it's own making.

However, electronics that can survive the forces of being fired from a cannon [are now a real thing](https://maritime-executive.com/article/darpa-develops-smart-bullet-for-deck-guns).

[image]

The main gun of an M1A1 tank has a muzzle velocity of ~1,600 meters per second. From the safe zone, it could propel a saboted sensor package across the gap and into the gate in under half a second.

The sensor package would capture as much as it could before melting.

However, there's another problem. The cloud of iron and glass gas is an effective block to radio and optical signals for the probe to send back. Sonic is unlikely to be effective either. Thankfully, some nice fellows have [invented neutrino communication](https://physicsworld.com/a/neutrino-based-communication-is-a-first/), which can communicate through solid rock.

### TL; DR

The portal would be incredibly hot, with an explosive blast spreading at Mach 3 from the portal area into the surroundings.

Comment: Just added expansion. Working on limits.

Comment: I see no kinetic element accounting for the different velocity of the two planets.

Comment: @l.dutch - Ha! Although I do wonder if the two phase transitions : gas to liquid, liquid to solid add much of a kick.

Comment: @L.Dutch I was assuming the Alien Space Magic would account for that with gate adjustments, although that could add some interesting dynamics.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me that the probe would reach the portal - the rocket will be crumpled by the pressure...and peppered by the condensing iron hailstones...and then deflected by the supersonic wind.

Comment: Very ingenious, but I fear an error has crept in somewhere. Air has a density of around 1.2kg/cubic meter at 15 degrees C and 1 atmosphere of pressure. Assuming the portal is 5 meters square that’s 25 square meters. So a wind speed of 2 m/s could push more than 50 kg/s through a portal sized hole. As the pressure on the other is 30,000 atmospheres I think a great deal more than that would be coming through.

Comment: "explosive blast spreading at Mach 3 from the portal area into the surrounding wilderness" OP did not say it was wilderness... but it's going to be wilderness anyways.

Comment: Well thought out answer, but a few suggestions: Tungsten with a melting point of 6192°F does not have the highest melting point of known materials.  Nitrogen Hafnium Carbide has a melting point of 7460°F.  Also, the OP does not specify °F °C or °K; so, if he means °F, then there are plenty of materials one could use.  If he means °C or °K, a plasma window may be another means to contain the atmosphere since they are not sensitive to silly things like melting.

Comment: The gas may cool around the portal building up a ring around it which would likely become like a volcano shape.

Comment: This answer is mostly on the right track, but it looks like there is an error in the math somewhere.  The choked flow rate through the portal should be $C_d A \sqrt{\gamma \rho_0 P_0 \left(\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\right)^{\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma-1}}}$ which evaluates to $4.8 \times 10^7$ kg/s according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi*%285+m+%2F+2%29%5E2+*+sqrt%281.29+*+%284394+kg%2Fm%5E3%29+*+%283.045+GPa%29+*+%282+%2F+%281.29%2B1%29%29%5E%28%281.29%2B1%29+%2F+%281.29-1%29%29%29).

Comment: I agree with @Thorondor, the term within the square root in the answer is missing a multiplication by pressure.  RSpecific is also calculated without taking into account units of mass as g vs kg.  I get a result of around 6 x 10^8 kg/s... but I may easily have miscalculated.  However, whether it's forty-eight thousand or six hundred thousand metric tons per second, those figures feel more like they're in the right ballpark... which is a far cry from a paltry 44 kg/s.  This would be a catastrophic, possibly even a global-extinction-level event if the flow didn't destroy the gate.

Comment: At 48000 to 600000 metric tons per second, white-hot iron-glass gas would be erupting from the portal at a speed that I calculated to be on the order of up to 7 km/s.  There's no way that you're getting anything other than a railgun shell through that portal... and that's assuming that anyone or anything survives long enough to fire it.

Comment: @Nosajimiki-ReinstateMonica The temperature is in K.

Comment: Wouldn't that portal basically be a giant rocket engine on our side?

Comment: @vsz that's the way I took it. Presumably held in place, relative to Earth, by the same alien space magic that created it.

Comment: So, from Hell side to our side the pressure drops from 30.000 atmospheres to 1. How hot is that hot gas still afterwards? Is the gas cooking the stuff on our side or freezing it? Does T1/T2 ~ 200 mean the temperature after expansion is 25K?

Comment: Is there some way you could use the Leidenfrost effect?

Comment: After expansion, should be the ambient room temperature. However, thermal energy is going to build up over time. But that build-up is a function of winds carrying the heat away or a lack of wind holding it in place.

Comment: @marcellothearcane - that's a really good idea. I'd like to try it out.

Comment: For those interested in heat transfer, you can calculate delta-q from m-dot, c (glass specific heat capacity), and T (5,000K). You'd also need to cover the heat of fusion and heat of vaporization. Because m-dot is very low, I expect delta-q might be reasonable.

Comment: So, Silicon Dioxide has a density of ~2500 kg/m^3, and iron's density is between ~7000-8000 kg/m^3 depending on the temperature.  Given that the overall density on the far side of the portal is is 4400 kg/m^3, then depending on the exact proportions of the components involved, that's going to be closer to a supercritical fluid if not a straight-up liquid rather than a true gas.  I don't know if that changes the outcome at all, but I figured it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @Thorondor sorry it took so long. I re-ran the math, and there was an error; but I get an m-dot 825 kg per second. I'm going to update the answer to add step-by-step.

Comment: @JamesMcLellan you are still missing the $P_0$ term.

Comment: P0 is provided in the question. 30,000 atmospheres. Which should be about 3 gigapacals.

Comment: Oh. I see it now.

Comment: Don't you still have RSpecific wrong?  You're using 60g/mol instead of 0.06kg/mol.  That makes RSpecific 138,567 instead of 138.6.

Answer (score 4):

Based on James McLellan's excellent, if (as of the moment I write this) slightly flawed answer, when this portal is opened, 5,000K, 30,000ATM iron-glass gas is going to erupt from the portal at a rate of around 600,000 metric tons per second.

At standard pressure and temperature (1 ATM), this gas would have a density of $0.1385kg/m^3$.  However, at 30000 ATM, its density would be around $4155kg/m^3$.  Dividing the mass flow of $600,000,000kg/s$ by the portal's area of $19.6m^2$ and the gas's density, we get a velocity of $7368m/s$, or approximately Mach 7.

Then we must consider that Silicon Dioxide has a specific heat of around $0.7J/g/K$, so each second we're adding $2×10^15J$ of energy to the surrounding area. That's on the order of a 476 kiloton bomb every second... or 2 petawatts of power... ten times the power output of the most powerful hurricanes.

This jet of superheated ultra-high pressure gas is going to ablate anything in its path in a roughly conical volume with its point within the portal, the centerline of the cone aligning with the centerline of the portal.

Eventually, the Earth's atmosphere and crust will absorb the momentum of the gaseous iron-glass, and it will also cool enough that it will condense as a liquid iron-glass mixture, which will behave rather like lava.

Initially, I expect that this iron-glass gas will cool rapidly as it expands into the earth's relatively cold atmosphere, probably before it loses its kinetic energy, with the result that it will condense into a liquid iron-glass spray that still retains a significant velocity.  It may even cool sufficiently in order to solidify before it loses its kinetic energy. At this point, there may well be sizeable droplets of iron-glass, but it is likely that there will also be a significant amount of finely divided material much like volcanic ash, that will remain suspended in the atmosphere for some time.

As the event continues, the earth's atmosphere will heat up, slowing the rate of cooling while still absorbing kinetic energy, meaning that eventually molten iron-glass will begin to rain down upon the landscape.

However, things don't stop there. The erupting gas will impart its kinetic energy to the earth's atmosphere, resulting in an accelerating hot wind in the direction of the jet cone.  This will distribute hot iron-glass ash - and as the atmospheric temperature increases, molten iron glass - around the world.

The global temperature will rise to the point where the entire earth is blanketed in a pyroclastic cloud, until the heat from the jet of superheated gas begins to melt the ash deposits around it, resulting in a flood of molten lava advancing toward the portal. Until the weight of molten glass around the portal is sufficient to counter the outflow, the outflow will not stop.

If we consider a planet big enough to have an atmosphere such as this, it will have way more atmosphere than Earth.  There is practically no way that it will run out of atmosphere before the earth is covered in a thick life-extinguishing layer of hot iron-rich glass.

Alternatively, the portal will fail at some point, saving the planet.  Whatever continent it was on is probably completely wiped out.

As for getting a probe through the portal... without a railgun, there's probably next to no chance, and even with one, no projectile will survive more than a fraction of a second in such a hellish environment. The probe would have to be launched toward the portal at the instant or even before the portal opened to have any chance of making it through... and it is likely that if the scientists in charge weren't aware of exactly to where they were opening a portal, any probe and recording device is unlikely to survive long enough to be launched, let alone return any data.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can be probed, but the probe will be very limited in what it can do.

Start with James McLellan's idea of firing a large gun into it.  He's got the wrong gun, though.  We want a large caliber artillery piece, not a tank.  (Yes, most artillery pieces can be fired horizontally.  You don't see it because it's a last ditch defensive move, not something they want to do.)

The propellant is calculated so that after passing through the gas streaming out of the portal it doesn't have much velocity left.  When it goes through the portal it opens up like a flower.  You now have an object with quite a surface area in a hypersonic wind, the wind is going to grab it and throw it back through the portal.

To be flung back through the portal it obviously can't go too far from it and it can't survive the heat for long--the data package is insulated as well as possible, the instruments have a very short lifespan before being destroyed.  The recorder is as light as possible, it needs to be blown by the wind far enough from the portal to survive and be recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, but no probe.  Map it from our side.**

1. Cap the portal.  You will need to approach it with the cap mounted on a bulldozer.  The bulldozer can be remotely driven.
2. Cap will of course need to withstand heat as well as pressure but pressure is constant, and so will not need to withstand sudden shocks or impacts.
3. Ideally cap would be in the shape of a dish and could be used as a radar dish.  If not (antenna not durable in hot atmosphere?), cap should be able to allow radar waves through it.  A refractory ceramic would work.
4. Map the far side thru the capped portal with radar.  Sonar might also be useful; high pressure gases on the far side will probably transmit sound well.

Comment: Capping could be a bit tricky: the air's 5500 degrees.  If that's 5500 F, there are plenty of materials that could do the job, but if it's 5500 C or 5500 K, even exotic ceramics such as hafnium carbide are going to melt.

Comment: The atmosphere of Hell is going to be coming through so fast and hot that it would be like driving a bulldozer into an atomic blast... literally.

Comment: Monty, Monty, @MontyWild.  You are right again.  And in any case the wind scooped out all the earth in front of the portal anyway.  But it is a portal.  We will approach from behind, out of the wind, and drop the cap over the front.

Comment: Just how long is any physical obstruction going to be able to hold against 5000K temperatures? Then, if you can find something that can take the heat, how do you get it into position when the flow that it's supposed to block is on the order of tens to hundreds of thousands of tons per second.